# how to search for all occurrences of a Tamil character in a line?

Tags: python, python-2.7, tamil

I am trying to write a program which checks the occurrence of a Tamil character in the line/sentence. I have written a code it checks if the character is present in the line and if so quits does not check for the second or third occurrence. Here is the code: 
(I have split the words into characters so I am checking with "word").

```
    count=0
    word="ஆ"
    f=open('input','r')
    for line in f.readlines():
        if word in line:
            count=count+1
    print count
    f.close()
```

the input file "input" has:

```
   ஆ ன் டை ன்  
   ஆ ன் டை னி ன் 
   ஆ ன் டொ வி ன் 
   ஆ ன் ட் டா ல ஜி 
   எ ன் றி ஆ ன் 
   ஆ ன் ட் ட ன் ஆ
```

the current output is:

```
count:6
```

but output should be:

```
count:7
```

In the last line it checks for the word `ஆ` it is present in the beginning, it quits after that. I want it to check the full line and count all occurrences. how should i modify it?

Comment: Please read http://bit.ly/unipain before continuing. Specifically, text should be in `u"unicode"` objects in Python 2.

Comment: thanx 4 d link. It says a lot on unicode processing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently you are only checking whether the character is in a line at all, but not counting the occurences. 
There's the `count` method for doing what you want: https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.count

```
>> 'hello world'.count('l')
3
```

Also, as Wooble already pointed out in his comment, you must take special care when using non-ascii characters in python2 (he provided you with the needed information).

Answer (score 0):

Try the `open-tamil` library, which you can install from `pip`:

```sh
$ pip install open-tamil
```

Here's how to use it:

```py
import tamil
letters_list = tamil.utf8.get_tamil_letters( string_input )
```